# javascript alert box in cancel

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

I have this code. It runs well but if you click CANCEL the first time it pops, the box continue running. I don´t know how to make it go to the page underneath if i click cancel the first time it pops.

```js
var numero= prompt ("introduce un numero")
    var resultado= parImpar(numero);
        alert ("el numero "+numero+" es "+resultado );
    
       
    
    function parImpar (numero){
       if (numero %2===0) {
          return "par" ;
       }
       else{
           return "impar" ;
       }
    }
    
    if (window.confirm ("Probemos otro numero ")){
     var numero= prompt ("Elegi");
     var resultado =parImpar (numero);
         alert("El numero "+numero+" es "+resultado );
        
    }else{
        
    }
```

```css
body {
    background-color:pink;
}
h1 {
   font-weight:bold; 
}
p{
   font-weight:bolder ;
   font-family: Garamond;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>First web! </h1>
            <p>Hi everyone! this is mi first ever page/program. I have been learning for a month now and i need it to understand some javascript functions. Im really fighting with them.</p>
            
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if the prompt returned null (cancel clicked) in order to avoid executing the next lines of code, like this

```
var numero= prompt ("introduce un numero")
if (numero != null) {//Cancel clicked!
      var resultado= parImpar(numero);
      alert ("el numero "+numero+" es "+resultado );
}
```

Comment: thanks! now i have another problem. Now it does not return "null" but it pops the second alert, i don´t want that. I want that in the first cancel click, it goes directly to de page

Comment: @NanaRepetto, then just add `if (window.confirm("Probemos otro numero ")) {...}` inside `if (numero != null) {...}` too.

Answer (score 0):

Now the code looks like this.
I´m missing a conditional, but i don´t know how to do it.
Sorry! i´ve been learning for a month now, i´m really struggling!!

```
var numero= prompt ("introduce un numero")
if (numero !== null) {//Cancel clicked!
      var resultado= parImpar(numero);
      alert ("el numero "+numero+" es "+resultado );
}else{


}

if (window.confirm ("Probemos otro numero ")){
 var numero= prompt ("Elegi");
 var resultado =parImpar (numero);
     alert("El numero "+numero+" es "+resultado );

}else{

}
function parImpar (numero){
   if (numero %2===0) {
      return "par" ;
   }
   else{
       return "impar" ;
   }
}
```